# MVC4 Mobile environment on xp

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to develop a simple sample mobile web app using MVC4, to provide a small demo to my team. Following is my machine config

OS: Windows XP
VS: VS 2010 express
Emulator: Android (i couldn't find windows7 emulator for xp)

Problem: Android Emulator needs (as far as i know) application to be hosted as IIS application
but when i create virtual directory for the MVC4 and try to access, it simple throws 403 error, thats because (again as far as i know) IIS 5.1 doesn't know MVC4 Request handling

Question: Now how to proceed in this situation to test the application on latest mobile (of any kind windows7, android or apple) emulator browser ?

I tried IIS Express, but android emulator didn't like it.

Comment: Can you serve content to a regular browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried mapping all requests to aspnet_isapi.dll?

See this blog post for instructions: http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.in/2008/11/deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-on-windows-xp-iis.html?m=1

Comment: He didn't indicate a problem serving up content to non-mobile emulators.

Comment: No, iis didn't serve the content to a regular browser. Anyway it is good working now, all that i had to do is register 4.0 FW, and follow instructions in the link you(@ michielvoo) provided. I did not update any routing code though.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried IIS Express, but android emulator didn't like it.

IIS Express is a web server (albeit better than Cassini), IIS Express is not your problem. The simplest emulators are Chrome/FF plug-ins and settings. See my  tutorial [ASP.NET MVC 4 Mobile Features](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features)

Comment: Yes, IIS Express was not the problem. Thank you for providing simplest emulator details and i will for sure go through the tutorial. Thank you so much.